# Future tasks in Java 1.6

Tags: java, multithreading, java-6

In Java 1.7 we can have future task where the rest of the processes of `obj` will continue in new threads without waiting for the results of another.

```
private static ExecutorService executorService 
  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

public void update(MyObject obj) {
    executorService.execute(new FutureTask<>(new MyFutureTask(obj)));  
}
```

Is there any way to do something similar to this in java 1.6?

Comment: Java 6 does not have the diamond operator, so delete it from the `new FutureTask` part.

Comment: Why are you passing FIFO_TYPE as the number of threads in the pool?

Comment: actually int FIFO_TYPE = 1

Comment: So you have a single threaded pool. Calling it FIFO_TYPE is a bit confusing. IMHO.

Comment: Please don't ask questions that you can answer yourself in 30 seconds by READING THE JAVADOCS ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`FutureTask<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) introduced in java 1.5, you can use it in java 1.6 without any doubt :) .

[Check the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder your answer really helped me and java 1.6 has Future Task in similar way.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html